# Speed up setting a lot of span positions

Tags: jquery, optimization, offset

I span every character of a paragraph with jQuery to animate it later.

```
// span each character
$('#testText p').children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
    }
});

// store each span
$spanCharacters = $('#testText p span');
```

I have around 800 characters. It goes very slow... I wondered if there is any way to get it faster.

Like now it creates a style for every span:

```
<span style="position: relative; top: 8.763065797205456px; left: 0px;">i</span>
```

Is it possible to change the position directly?

Here is the complete code, notice i have the draw method off!

If you turn it on, be aware things go slowly.

```
var TWO_PI = 6.2831855;

var frameCount = 0;

var $spanCharacters = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {   

    // span each character
    $('#testText p').children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>"));
        }
    });

    // store each span
    $spanCharacters = $('#testText p span');

    //var handle = setInterval(draw, 80);
    draw();

});



function draw() {
    frameCount++;

    var width = 500;


    $spanCharacters.each(function() {

        var offsetLeft = $(this).offset().left;
        var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;

       var posLeft = $(this).position().left;

       var a = map(posLeft+frameCount, 0, width/5, 0, TWO_PI);
       var c = Math.cos(a);

        var addOffset = c*10;
        //console.log(addOffset);

       $(this).offset({ top: offsetTop+addOffset, left: offsetLeft });

    });
}

function map(value, istart, istop, ostart, ostop) {
    return ostart + (ostop - ostart) * ((value - istart) / (istop - istart));
 }
```

So in short, how can this be sped up?

http://jsfiddle.net/LwD42/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.offset()` does a lot of checks you probably don't need. You should also cache your jQuery objects instead of constantly recreating them. For example:

Replace `$(this)` with `var self = $(this)` and just make calls to `self`. Everytime you use the `$()` function jQuery creates another object.

You could do the following which would be much faster:

```
$spanCharacters.each(function() {
   var a = map(this.offsetLeft + frameCount, 0, width/5, 0, TWO_PI);
   var c = Math.cos(a);

   var addOffset = c * 10;

   this.style.position = "relative";
   this.style.top = addOffset + "px";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LwD42/9/

Here is a performance test comparing the two: http://jsperf.com/span-position-speed-test/ 
This version is roughly twice as fast in my browser. It is still relatively slow but this always will be as you are editing such a large number of DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @George Reith answer. You could optimize the string manipulation to one DOM insert:

```
 // span each character
var text = "", 
    topOffset = 0;
$('#testText p').children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var $this = $(this);
        text += $this.text().replace(/(\w)/g, "<span>$&</span>");
    }
}).replaceWith(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the framecount to move more than 1

```
function draw() {
frameCount+=10;
var width = 500;
$spanCharacters.each(function() {
   var offsetLeft = $(this).offset().left;
   var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
   var posLeft = $(this).position().left;
   var a = map(posLeft+frameCount, 0, width/5, 0, TWO_PI);
   var c = Math.cos(a);
   var addOffset = c*10;
   $(this).offset({ top: offsetTop+addOffset, left: offsetLeft });
});
}
```

i use .animate to set the top on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwD42/12/)